# How to change alpha of text in Textfield

Tags: iphone, alpha, placeholder

I have set default text to UItextfield. Now I want to change alpha value of default text. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer:

```
[self.objTextFieldSearch setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:140.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:0.5] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

Provides desired result.